# vba listbox to show background color for header

Tags: vba

I want to show different background color to row 1 in listback.  I am using below code to color but it is changing entire background for all listbox rows. Please help if there is anyway to color first row of listbox.

```
UserForm4.ListBox15.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)

If lv_item = 0 Then
    UserForm4.ListBox15.AddItem "Sr no" 'Additem creates a new row
    UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 1) = "Volumn Processed"
    UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 2) = "Volumn Target"
    UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 3) = "Approached"
    UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 4) = "Confidence Level"
End If

lv_item = 1

With rs
    rs.MoveFirst
    While Not rs.EOF
        UserForm4.ListBox15.AddItem rs.Fields("Sr no").Value 'Additem creates a new row
        UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 1) = rs.Fields("Volumn Processed").Value
        UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 2) = rs.Fields("Volumn Target").Value
        UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 3) = rs.Fields("Approached").Value
        UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 4) = rs.Fields("Confidence Level").Value
        UserForm4.ListBox15.List(lv_item, 6) = rs.Fields("Unique ID").Value
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and will not build. Please correct it. To answer your question, you cannot change the color on a single row only.

Comment: You can change the color and the backcolor of a single row in a listbox, but it is subclassing the listbox. There are examples when you look for VB6 Listbox Item Color [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808399/change-some-listbox-items-fore-color-in-vb6) but you have to do some work on it, because of the handles you need. You should be very experienced for that.